# React js Image Upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

```
xport default function AccountVerification(props) {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.AuthReducer);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [countryData, setCountry] = React.useState([]);
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);
  const [isverified, setIsverified] = useState(0)
  const [usercountry, setUserCountry] = useState('india');
  const [id_no, setIdNo] = useState('');
  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState('');
  const [personalTab, setPersonalTab] = useState(0);
  const [isSubmitPersonalData, setSubmitPersonalData] = useState(0);
  const [id_verification, setIdVerifocation] = useState(0)
  const [filedata, setFileData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    N_checkKYCStatus(user?.params ? user.params.token: user.token)
    .then((d)=>{
      if (d.status === 200) {
        if(d?.params.status == 2) {
          setPersonalTab(1);
        } 
        else if(d?.params.status == 4) {
          setPersonalTab(4)
        }else if(d?.params.status == -1) {
          setIsverified(2)
        } else if(d?.params.status == 1) {
          setIsverified(1)
        }
        if(d?.params.status == 0 || d?.params.status == 3) {
          N_getCountry(user?.params ? user.params.token : user.token)
          .then((d) => {
            if (d.status === 200) {
              setCountry(d?.params.country_data);
            }
           
          })
        }
      }
      setLoading(false);
    })
   
  }, []);


  const updatePersonal = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    N_profileData(user?.params ? user.params.token: user.token, type, id_no, first_name, last_name, usercountry)
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      if(res.status == 200) {
        setSubmitPersonalData(2);
      }
    })
  }

  function readURL(input) {
    const file = input.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      setFileData(file);
      setIdVerifocation(3)
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#check_photo").attr("src", e.target.result);
      };
    }
  }


  <div className={id_verification==3?'':'d-none'} id="preview_photo">
                  <div class="steps_div">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no">1</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">Personal Information</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="adjacent_line"></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no active">2</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">
                        ID Verification & Face Verification
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 m-auto col-12 mb-3">
                      <div className="jambotron border-dashed">
                        <div className="photo-preview">
                          {" "}
                          <img
                            src="/img/placeholder-id-front.svg"
                            className="img-fluid"
                            id="check_photo"
                            alt="placeholder-id-front"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="big_heading text-center">
                          Check Photo
                        </h4>

                        <ul className="my-3">
                          <li>Have you checked if your ID is supported? </li>
                          <li>Can you read the details?</li>
                          <li>Can you see the whole ID?</li>
                        </ul>
                     
                        <div className="text-center">
                          <button className="btn btn-secondary my-2 me-2"
                          onClick={(e)=>{
                            setIdVerifocation(2)
                          }}
                          >
                            Try again
                          </button>
                          <button className="btn btn-primary my-2"
                           onClick={(e) => {
                            N_uploadID(
                              e,
                              filedata,
                              "docf",
                              user?.params ? user.params.token : user.token
                            );
                            setIdVerifocation(2)
                            setPersonalTab(4)
                          }}>
                            Confirm
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </>
                :null}
                {personalTab == 4?
                <>
                {/* Start Verification */}
                <div className={id_verification==0?'':'d-none'} id="start_verification">
                  <div class="steps_div">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no">1</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">Personal Information</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="adjacent_line"></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no active">2</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">
                        ID Verification & Face Verification
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <h4 class="big_heading text-center">
                    <BiSolidCheckShield className="me-1 text-green" /> Start
                    Verfication
                  </h4>
                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 m-auto col-12 mb-3">
                      <div className="jambotron">
                        <p>
                          {" "}
                          This process is designed to verify your identity and
                          protect you from identity theft.
                        </p>

                        <p>Please have your ID ready and click 'Start'. </p>
                      </div>

                      <div className="d-flex align-items-center gap-1 my-3">
                        <div>
                          {" "}
                          <BiError className="text-warning fs-4" />{" "}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          This page will expire in a few minutes if you do not
                          start.
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div className="d-grid mb-2">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                        onClick={(e)=>{
                          setIdVerifocation(1)
                        }}>
                          Start
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <p className="small text-muted">
                        By clicking “Start” you consent to Jumio collecting and
                        disclosing your biometric data pursuant to its{" "}
                        <a href="#" className="text-info">
                          Privacy Policy
                        </a>
                        .
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                {/* choose method to upload Documents */}
                <div className={id_verification == 1?"":"d-none"} id="choose_method">
                  <div class="steps_div">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no">1</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">Personal Information</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="adjacent_line"></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no active">2</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">
                        ID Verification & Face Verification
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <h4 class="big_heading text-center">
                    Choose an Upload Method
                  </h4>
                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 m-auto col-12 mb-3">
                      {/* <div className=" mb-2">
                        <a href="#" className="upload_btn active">
                          <BiMobileAlt className="me-1 fs-4" /> Continue On
                          mobile
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div className=" mb-2">
                        <a href="#" className="upload_btn">
                          <AiOutlineCamera className="me-1 fs-4" /> Take photo
                          using webcam
                        </a>
                      </div> */}
                      <div className=" mb-2">
                        <button className="upload_btn"
                        onClick={(e)=>{
                          setIdVerifocation(2)
                        }}>
                          <AiOutlineCloudUpload className="me-1 fs-4" /> Upload
                          file from this device
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                {/* Upload front of ID Card */}
                <div className={id_verification==2?'':'d-none'}  id="upload_doc">
                  <div class="steps_div">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no">1</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">Personal Information</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="adjacent_line"></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no active">2</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">
                        ID Verification & Face Verification
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 m-auto col-12 mb-3">
                      <div className="jambotron border-dashed text-center">
                        <div className="dummy-card-photo">
                          {" "}
                          <img
                            src="/img/placeholder-id-front.svg"
                            className="img-fluid"
                            alt="placeholder-id-front"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="big_heading text-center">
                          Upload Back of identity card
                        </h4>

                        <div className="badge bg-dark fs-12 my-2">
                          Step 2 of 2
                        </div>
                        <p>
                          Upload a color image of the entire document.
                          Screenshots are not allowed. JPG, JPEG or PNG format
                          only.
                        </p>
                        <div className="d-grid">
                        <input
                            id="upload_front_adhar"
                            type="file"
                            onChange={(e) => {
                              readURL(e);
                            }}
                            className="form-control kyc_image--"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


                 {/* Preview of photo */}
                 <div className={id_verification==3?'':'d-none'} id="preview_photo">
                  <div class="steps_div">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no">1</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">Personal Information</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="adjacent_line"></div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                      <div class="circle_no active">2</div>
                      <span class="text-lgray">
                        ID Verification & Face Verification
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-lg-9 m-auto col-12 mb-3">
                      <div className="jambotron border-dashed">
                        <div className="photo-preview">
                          {" "}
                          <img
                            src="/img/placeholder-id-front.svg"
                            className="img-fluid"
                            id="check_photo"
                            alt="placeholder-id-front"
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4 class="big_heading text-center">
                          Check Photo
                        </h4>

                        <ul className="my-3">
                          <li>Have you checked if your ID is supported? </li>
                          <li>Can you read the details?</li>
                          <li>Can you see the whole ID?</li>
                        </ul>
                     
                        <div className="text-center">
                          <button className="btn btn-secondary my-2 me-2"
                          onClick={(e)=>{
                            setIdVerifocation(2)
                          }}
                          >
                            Try again
                          </button>
                          <button className="btn btn-primary my-2"
                           onClick={(e) => {
                            N_uploadID(
                              e,
                              filedata,
                              "docb",
                              user?.params ? user.params.token : user.token
                            );
                          }}>
                            Confirm
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </>
                :null}

              </div>
```

when i upload image show error 400 but send 2nd image upload selection in the screen when 1st image error image not upload the through 2nd image and when i upload second image sucesfully upload but  1st image has not upload when only 2nd iamge are sucesfully upload 1st image are not upload and not show any error to upload first image